# Combining Laravel + Vue.js I got Error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './vue/app'"

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I did everything exactly as in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHSipe7pSac
but I got this error i cmd :(
"ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 4:0-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './vue/app' in 'D:\osp\domains\laravel-todolist\resources\js'
webpack compiled with 1 error" and error in browser console "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './vue/app'".

Here is my short overview video with my code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZqYJaIgau4

I created folder /vue/ in /resources/js/ folder and put here file 'app.vue' with code

```
<template><div>Hello</div></template> <script>export default {}</script>
```

Then in /resources/js/app.js file I'm importing Vue instance and my template file.

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './vue/app';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App }
})
```

Please help understand where is the problem :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're probably using Vue3 with Laravel Mix 6 so, in short, in your **webpack.mix.js**, instead of this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

Use this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks. It's work. But it's not 3, just old good vue 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue from the same tutorial and tried the solution here but my error was still not resolved.

this is what I did. I used - 1.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
```

- 2. I install npm again with `npm install` because I was told some packages weren't installed.
- 3. I install vue again with `npm install vue`,
- 4. I did `npm run dev` and finally `npm run watch`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder in your project folder.
2. Delete the `npm` and `npm-cache` folders in the `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming` and the `C:\Users\AppData\Local paths.`
3. Reinstall the node modules afresh using `npm install`
4. Install the `Vue` package `npm install vue`. In the `webpack.mix.js` file replace this (since it is mix version 6.0)

   ```
     mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
     //
     ]);
   ```

with

```
      <code>mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
     .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
     //
     ]);
```

5. Run `npm run hot.` The error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace

   ```
   mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
           //
       ]);
   ```

   by

   ```
   mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
       .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
           //
       ]);
   ```
2. Run the below in the command prompt

   ```
    npm i vue-loader
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my webpack.mix.js file i replaced this

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
```

with this

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
```

But i was still getting errors when i run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`
after hours of searching it turned out i was using vue-loader 17 with Vue 2. If you want to use Vue 2 the latest supported version of vue-loader is 15, vue-loader 16 and up is purely made for Vue 3. I downgraded to vue-loader 15.9.8 and everything runs green.